# How to convert an object to array with correct data types in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, integer, boolean

Trying to take an object like:

```
var object = {name: joe, age: 23, student: true}
```

I need to convert this to an array like:

```
["joe", 23, true]
```

Since objects treat all properties as strings, how do I format them properly for an array? The function also has to be dynamic, not hard coded object.

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here. JavaScript does treat all *keys* of an object as strings, but the value of the key can be of any type. In any case, take a look at the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) function.

Comment: Ah yes ok. Sorry new to all this. The example would be a string, number and boolean for values. That's probably the confusion on my end.

Comment: But joe is not a string, as you use it- it is a reference to a variable in the enclosing scope. Unless joe === 'joe' this doesn't make sense. It's impossible to know what value the variable joe has without seeing the surrounding context.

Now, this would make more sense if you wrote: ```var object = {name: 'joe', age: 23, student: true}``` In that case protoproto's answer is fine. But this is not a trivial quibble- you seem to be a bit confused about the distinction between how keys and values are handled in JS objects, and you should figure this out because it will otherwise bite you.

Answer (score 2):

Use object values:

```js
var object = {name: "joe", age: 23, student: true}
console.log(Object.values(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `Object.values()` will do the trick for you.Another way to do it is using `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
var obj = {
  name: 'joe',
  age: 23,
  student: true
};
const result = Object.keys(obj).map((elm) => obj[elm]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes this works. Is the old way to write this like: `for (var key in object) {
    array.push(object[key]) } ` ?

Comment: @demiansims yes but I prefer `map()` :)